# How to auto refresh token in Nuxt.js Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to know how to auto refresh token in `Nuxt.js` and I want to refresh token after it expires.

Now I use this code in plugin/axios.js

```
if (code === 401) {
    const { email } = store.state.auth.auth.user
    const { refreshToken } = store.state.auth.auth.token

    $axios.$post(`${process.cnv.baseUrl}/v1/auth/refresh-token`, {
        email, refreshToken 
    })
    .then(res => {
        // set new token
    })
}
```

Comment: check this once https://stackoverflow.com/a/53866447/4523764

Answer (score 0):

Check this once
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53866447/4523764

You are trying to refresh the user with refresh token if I am not wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I also started to implement it manually before noticing the "Refresh" scheme available in the new doc: https://dev.auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/refresh

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)